# DIAC in series combination?

Tags: diac

I wanted to make a cheap and simple high voltage protection circuit which can turn off my appliance for 10 sec when high voltage hits. Generally DIAC works on 30volts. I have dozens of these DIAC I wanted to join them in series so that when ever 400volt hits (followed by relay) my application can be saved from high voltage.
Can anyone tell me how to increase breakover voltage ( VBO ) of a DIAC? Can i join it in series in order to achieve this.

Comment: Putting DIACS in series *might* work with a balancing resistors across each. However, their current limit is low, and might not protect the circuit.

Comment: @DrMoishe Pippik thanks a lot for reply.

Comment: Why not use a SIDAC instead?